# Pass Mono to the last map

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

I'm trying to make this code reactive, but without any luck.

This is the old code:

```
public BookInfo get( int libraryId )
{
    Optional<Book> optionalBook = bookRepository.findByLibraryId( bookId );

    int bookId = optionalBook
        .map( b -> b.id() + 1 )
        .orElse( 0 );
    
    return bookRepository.findById( bookId )
                         .map( pages -> new BookInfo( optionalBook, pages ) );
}
```

This is what I came up with so far:

```
public Mono<BookInfo> get( int libraryId )
{
    return bookRepository.findByLibraryId( bookId )
                         .flatMap( book -> bookRepository.findById( book.id() ) )
                         .switchIfEmpty( Mono.defer( () -> bookRepository.findById( 0 ) ) )
                         .map( pages -> new BookInfo( null, pages ) );
}
```

This issue is how can I get the book returned by the `findByLibraryId` method to the last map?

For this case I only need to pass in an extra value to the last map but what if I have to pass multiples?

Thanks

Comment: So `bookRepository.findByLibraryId(...)` returns a book but `bookRepository.findById(...)` returns the pages of a book? How about replacing `flatMap()` with `map()` and some logic (not sure if that would break the reactive style though)?

Answer (score 1):

In functional libraries like Reactor you can pass arguments from previous steps by nesting. In your case you can achieve this by calling `map` inside the `flatMap`.

Here are two examples of doing this. Both are equivalent so choose the one by your own preference:

Code block 1: map at both Monos

```java
public Mono<BookInfo> get(int bookId) {
    return bookRepository.findByLibraryId(bookId)
            .flatMap(book -> bookRepository.findById(book.id() + 1)
                    .map(pages -> new BookInfo(Optional.of(book), pages)))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> bookRepository.findById(0)
                    .map(pages -> new BookInfo(Optional.empty(), pages))));
}
```

Code block 2: map at one Mono by first mapping to an Optional

```java
public Mono<BookInfo> get2(int bookId) {
    return bookRepository.findByLibraryId(bookId)
            .map(Optional::of)
            .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty())
            .flatMap(optionalBook -> bookRepository.findById(
                            optionalBook.map(book -> book.id() + 1).orElse(0))
                    .map(pages -> new BookInfo(optionalBook, pages)));
}
```

Note that in both cases, the `map` has access to book/optionalBook.